# Understanding the proof 3

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation, modular-forms

Show that $S_6(\Gamma_0(4))=\eta^{12}(2z)\mathbb{C}$

where  $\eta(z)=e^{2\pi i z/24}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-e^{2\pi i nz})$  is the eta-function .

$S_6(\Gamma_0(4))$ is the space of cusp forms of weight 6 on $$ 
\Gamma_0(4))=\Big\lbrace\begin{pmatrix} 
a & b \\
c & d \\ 
\end{pmatrix}\in Sl_2(\mathbb{Z}):c\equiv0 \ mod  \ 4  \Big\rbrace  $$

Proof. If  $ f\in  S_6(\Gamma_0(4))$ , we must have a zero of order at least $1$ at each of $i\infty$ , $1/2$ and $0$ . Then for some $\lambda$, $f(z)-\lambda\eta^{12}(2z)$ has a zero of order $2$ at $i\infty$ . By
Sturm’s bound we deduce $f(z)=\lambda\eta^{12}(2z) .$

1. Is it from defintion of cusp forms that $f $ must have a zero of order at least $1$ at $i\infty,0,1/2$ ?
2. Why does $f(z)-\lambda\eta^{12}(2z)$ have a zero of order 2 at $i\infty$ ?

Thanks for the help .

Comment: I'm almost sure I know what you're talking about (modular forms, the modular group, congruence subgroups and etc.), but it is likely many people doesn't. Why don't you explain at least your different names and symbols?

Comment: You are a  bit confused. The zeros are when expressed as function of $q=\exp(2\pi i z)$. For example: $\, \eta^{12}(2z) = q - 12q^3 + 54q^5 + ...\,$ at $z = i\infty$.

Comment: Do you mean for q=0 $\eta^{12}(2z)$ is zero at $z=i\infty$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier coefficients of
$\, \eta^{12}(2z) = q - 12q^3 + 45q^5 + \dots\,$ where $\, q:=\exp(2\pi i z)\,$  is the [OEIS sequence A000735](https://oeis.org/A000735).
The three inequivalent cusps are $0, 1/2, i\infty$. The
Fourier coefficients in $A000735$ give the behavior at $\,z = i\infty\,$ since
$\,q=0\,$ there.
By definition of [Cusp form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_form) the Fourier series must have zero constant term and this refers to $\,q=0\,$ or equivalently to $\,z=i\infty.\,$
 Use $\, f(-1/(4z)) = 64 (z/i)^6 f(z)\,$ to get the behavior
at $\,z=0.\,$ Use $\,f(1/2+z) = -f(z)\,$ to get the behavior at $\,z=1/2.\,$